# Linux: mount a "striped" disk image?

Tags: mount, image, fat32

For various unpleasant reasons involving very large files and FAT32, I'd like to know if there is any way I can create a mountable disk image which is stored in multiple smaller (ie, "smaller than 4GB") files — for example, like OS X's sparse bundles.

Performance *isn't* a concern, so a solution involving, eg, FUSE or TrueCrypt would be completely acceptable.

(of course, I realize that one option would be to reformat the FAT32 disk… But that would create other problems, so I'd like to rule out this possibility before I think about them)

Comment: I suppose *one* option would be to create a VirtualBox virtual machine with a split disk… But that's just a *little* more overhead than I'm hoping for…

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is rarfs... which isn't what you're looking for (allows mounting a uncompressed split rar using FUSE)

rarfs mounts the archive read-only, so this might not be a great solution. And as far as I know most tools don't allow adding files to an archive that's already been split.